# postgres and docker-compose : can't create a custom role and database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'am trying to create a simple postgreSQL container with a custum user and database.

This is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  db.postgres:
    container_name: db.postgres
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER:'myuser'
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:'myuserpassword'
      - POSTGRES_DB:'mydb'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And the error when I try to connect to my database.

```
docker exec -it db.postgres psql -U myuser myuserpassword
psql: FATAL:  role "myuser" does not exist
```

OR

```
$ docker exec -it db.postgres /bin/bash
root@1a0531e0350f:/# psql -U myuser
psql: FATAL:  role "myuser" does not exist
```

Docker-compose environment variables appear to be ignored when creating the database.

I don't known what can I do. Do you have an idea of ​​the problem?

Thanks !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modify your docker-compose.yml file as below:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db.postgres:
    container_name: db.postgres
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myuserpassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Then drop your current data entirely and re-run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Thanks ! but I don't undestand on lot of documentation they use the notation "ENV_VAR: value"   for example : https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ or https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#-via-docker-stack-deploy-or-docker-compose

Comment: I had to remove the docker volume for postgres
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/203#issuecomment-255200501

Comment: You either use `- VAR=value` or `VAR: value`