# Docker Compose, Django: role "_" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

**Context**
I am trying to run my Django application and Postgres database in a docker development environment using docker-compose (it's my first time using Docker). 
I want to use my application with a custom role and database both named `teddycrepineau` (as opposed to using the default postgres user and db).

**Goal**
My goal is to deploy a web app powered on the front end by react and the backend by django restapi, the whole running in a docker.

**System/Version**

- python: 3.7
- django: 2.1
- OS: Mac OS High Sierra

**What error am I getting**
When running `docker-compose up` with my custom role and db, I am getting the following error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "teddycrepineau" does not exist`. When running the same command with the default role and db `postgres` Django is able to start normally.

My understanding was that running docker-compose up would create the role and db passed as environment variable.

**What I have tried so far**
I read multiple threat on this site, GitHub, and docker:

- tried to delete my container and rebuilt it with formatting as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112545/postgres-and-docker-compose-cant-create-a-custom-role-and-database)
- Went through [this](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/41) GitHub issue
- Tried to move my environment variable from `.env` file the `environment` inside my `docker-compose.yml` file and rebuild my container

---

### Files

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes: 
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "5432"

  django:
    build:
      context: teddycrepineau-backend
      dockerfile: teddycrepineau-root/Dockerfile
    command: ./teddycrepineau-backend/teddycrepineau-root/start.sh
    env_file: .env
    volumes: 
      - .:/teddycrepineau-backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /teddycrepineau-backend/
ADD ./teddycrepineau-root/requirements.txt /teddycrepineau-backend/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /teddycrepineau-backend/
RUN chmod +x ./teddycrepineau-root/start.sh
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python3 ./teddycrepineau-backend/teddycrepineau-root/manage.py runserver
```

**.env**

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD= 
POSTGRES_USER=teddycrepineau
POSTGRES_DB=teddycrepineau
```

---

**EDIT**

My file structure is as follow

```
root
 |___ teddycrepineau-backend
        |___ teddycrepineau-root
               |___ teddycrepineau
               |___ Dockerfile
               |___ manage.py
               |___ start.sh
 |___ teddycrepineau-frontend
        |___ React-App

 |___ .env
 |___ docker-compose.yml
```

When I move my docker-compose.yml file inside my backend folder, it starts as expected (though I am not able to access my site when going to `127.0.0.1:8000` but that is mostly a different issue) with custom user and db. When I put my `docker-compose.yml` file to my root folder, I get the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "teddycrepineau" does not exist`

Comment: typing error `POSTGES_USER=teddycrepineau` => `POSTGRES_USER=teddycrepineau`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, but I am still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because your pgsql db was launched without any envs. The pgsql docker image only uses the envs the first time you created the container, after that it won't recreate DB and users.

The solution is to remove the pgsql volume so next time you `docker-compose up` you will have a fresh db with envs read. Simple way to do it is `docker-compose down -v`

Comment: This is the correct answer.  OP says he recreated the container, but the actual tables and data aren't in the container due to the `volumes` entries.  Recreating the container doesn't wipe the existing database and tables, you need to erase everything in "postgres_data".

Comment: ...  does `docker-compose down` actually remove local files mapped into the container via `volumes`?

Comment: @TimTisdall thanks for reminding me... By default `docker-compose down` does not remove named volumes, so `-v` is needed

Comment: does that actually delete the local files, though?  I use `volumes` to map my code base into an instance and it seems bad if that command actually deleted all contents mapped with a volume.  For example, he has '.' mapped to a volume, so wouldn't that command delete the docker-compose.yml?!

Comment: @TimTisdall no. Named volumes (in op's case, `postgres_data`) and anonyme volumes will be removed, mounted volumes(`local/path:container/path`) will not be removed.

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you. I ran `docker-compose up` the very first time without a .env file but with a named volum. Even though I was running `docker-compose down`, `docker system prune`, and `docker-compose build` it would never delete and rebuild my volum.

Comment: Wow. Saved my day

Comment: Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Change your env order like this.

```
POSTGRES_DB=teddycrepineau
POSTGRES_USER=teddycrepineau
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
```

I find it at [this issue](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/41#issuecomment-382925263). I hope it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I posted an edit though

Answer (score 0):

when you run the

```
sudo docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate
```

yes of course you will receive

***"django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: role "user" does not exist***

first you need to put

```
sudo docker-compose down -v
sudo docker system prune
```

check container, they should be deleted

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

then check images

```
sudo docker image ls
```

don`t forget delete images

```
sudo docker image rm 3e57319a7a3a
```

run to the project folder and then check out

```
python manage.py migrate
```

if it didn`t works put the

```
python manage.py migrate —run-syncdb
```

and

```
sudo docker-compose up -d --build

sudo  docker-compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

sudo docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations
sudo docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate auth
sudo docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue due to a mismatch between the `$POSTGRES_DB` and `$POSTGRES_USER` variables. By default, psql will attempt to set the database to the same name as the user logging in, so when there is a mismatch between the variables it fails with an error along the lines of psql:

> FATAL: database "root" does not exist

I had to edit the init script that I was writing to include the `-d "$POSTGRES_DB"` option like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER docker;
        CREATE DATABASE docker;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;

EOSQL
```